# Why is my Multiple Select Field only returning one value?

Tags: python, html, django

I am a beginner in Django and web development in general. I have this page in which the user will choose which tags they'd like to search for and the program will search for images which contain that tag. Here's the form page:

```
<form action="{% url 'search' %}" method="post"> 
    {% csrf_token %}
    <select name="psearch" id="psearch" multiple>
        {% for tag in tags %}
        <option value="{{tag.name}}">{{tag.name}}</option>
        {% endfor %}
    </select>
    <button type="submit">Search</button>
</form>
```

Which produces this:
[image]

However, when I try to obtain the choices for the actual search it seems to only return one value. Here's the actual view which will require this information.

```
def search_view(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        psearch = request.POST['psearch']
        images = Image.objects.filter(tags__name = psearch)
        return render(request, 'search.html', {'psearch':psearch,
                                               'images': images})
    else:
        return render(request, 'search.html', {})
```

I have tried printing the actual result of psearch, for testing, here's an example:
[image]

I selected 'Praia' and 'Barco', however the according to the terminal outcome was just Barco:
[image]

How can I make this return as a list of all selected objects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't, it is just how subscripting `request.POST` works: it will return the *last* picked item.

You should use [**`.getlist(…)`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/request-response/#django.http.QueryDict.getlist) instead:

```
def search_view(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        psearch = request.POST.getlist('psearch')
        images = Image.objects.filter(tags__name__in=psearch)
        return render(
            request, 'search.html', {'psearch': psearch, 'images': images}
        )
    else:
        return render(request, 'search.html', {})
```

---

> **Note**: Searching is usually done through a GET request, since that means the query is stored in the querystring and thus the URL. This makes it convenient to for example share the URL with the query to someone else, or bookmark the result. POST requests are usually used for state-changing actions, or for requests with *sensitive* data.

Comment: Yeah that did it, thanks for the help and the advice!